# что такое делегаты и как их использовать?

Tags: c++, делегаты, unreal-engine-4

Я от слова совсем не могу понять для чего нужны делегаты и как с ними взаимодействовать.
Я увидел пример:

```
DECLARE_DYNAMIC_MULTICAST_DELEGATE_TwoParams(FOnColorChanged,const FLinearColor&, Color, const FString&, Name);
```

функция `FOnColorChanged` логирует смену цвета actor.Дальше что для чегo, понять не могу.

Буду очень благодарен если кто-то сможет обьяснить более на просто языке для чего делегаты и как с ними работать

Comment: Делегат, это такой объект, который может вызвать любую функцию, пусть это даже будет член-функция, обёртка так сказать над вызовом.  С перегруженным оператором ()

Comment: для чего эта обертка?почему нельзя просто вызвать метод?@ori

Comment: Потому что не всегда известно какой объект будет передан, и какая функция будет вызвана, а делегат сам разберётся ка и что вызвать.